# UnboundLocalError : Getting exception in a class attribute declaration

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Human:
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        population += 1

human = Human("Name", 12, "M")
print(Human.population)
```

The above code throws `UnboundLocalError` Exception.
**Full statement :** `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'population' referenced before assignment`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `Human.population += 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human is a class attribute accessible via `Human.population` inside the class

It is accessible outside class via `human.population` or `Human.population`

```
class Human:
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        #Access class attribute via ClassName inside class definition
        Human.population += 1

human = Human("Name", 12, "M")
#Access class attribute via ClassName outside class definition
print(Human.population)
#Access class attribute via Class instance outside class definition
print(human.population)
```

The output will be

```
1
1
```